# In SQL Server, Split bit column to 2 columns using PIVOT

Tags: sql-server

I have a table as below

```
Name     Grade  SubjectAorB
Pooja    B      1
Preeti   C      0
Preeti   C      1
Chintu   A      1
Deepika  B      0
Deepika  B      1
Peter    A      0
John     A      0
```

Last column `SubjectAorB` has values as 0 and 1. 0 means Subject A and 1 means Subject B. A student can have either of the subject or both. I want output as below:

```
Name    Grade   Subject A   Subject B
Pooja   B       0           1
Preeti  C       1           1
Chintu  A       0           1
Deepika B       1           1
Peter   A       1           0
John    A       1           0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT
    Name,
    Grade,
    SubjectA = MAX(CASE WHEN SubjectAorB = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
    SubjectB = MAX(CASE WHEN SubjectAorB = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
FROM #tbl
GROUP BY Name, Grade
```